# LINQ: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection.

Tags: .net, linq, .net-4.0

I have a `Dictionary<string, mystruct>` instance, for which I am grabbing a list of all values:

```
var list = m_Records.Values.ToList();
```

I occassionally get the following error:

```
ArgumentException
Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
```

I'm trying to figure out how that is even possible from that one very basic line.  When VS2010 breaks on that error, I can inspect `m_Records` and see it has, say, 24 entries (varies a bit).  But it *does* have values, and m_Records is certainly not null.

Comment: Is the Dictionary thread safe? In other words, are other threads modifying/reading that dictionary in the same time? (f.e. a static dictionary in an ASP.NET context

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you by chance modifying the dictionary on another thread while calling `ToList`? That will cause this error, and only occasionally, as you say, as such issues depend on thread timing issues which are notoriously persnickety. I can't think of any other reason this would happen.

Instead, you should be using `ConcurrentDictionary` (or, stop multi-threading). (Doc, it hurts when I do *this*. Then don't do *that*.)

Comment: @Darin: I didn't want to say that some of his answers are incorrect, i only wanted to say that people with huge reputation have the advantage that people will upvote faster assuming the correctness, others will follow because it's already pushed up to the top.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes, I have also observed this behavior.

Comment: By the way, in case it's not clear, which I know on the Internet it's very easy to be misunderstood, I was merely joking. I tend to assume the simplest explanation is correct: they upvoted his answer because it's better than mine.

Comment: Alternatively, one can `lock` the dictionary wherever it is being used. The lock object should be provided as a shared static property.

Answer (score 6):

If this is just LINQ to Objects, I strongly suspect that you're accessing the dictionary from a different thread at the same time. I'd be very surprised to see it fail otherwise. (`ToList` [isn't particularly complicated to implement](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-20-tolist.aspx) - I doubt that the BCL team messed this one up.)

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is *not* thread-safe if any threads are modifying it. If you need one which is, you should look at [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) in .NET 4.

Otherwise, just make sure you only access the dictionary (for read *or* write) in one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This error shows up if something is modifying your Dictionary while you're reading it. Dictionaries aren't thread safe for writing, if you need them to be you should use ConcurrentDictionary.